# Собака - происхождение слова

Tags: этимология

Когда появилось слово "собака" в русском языке? Что если английский купец пришел на двор к русскому коллеге лет 300 назад и удивился, как лает собака хозяина.

Comment: конечно удивился. ведь та собака лаяла по-русски, она же не общалась со своими английскими коллегами

Answer (score 4):

Вполне возможно, в 12 веке. Раньше на Руси было слово пёс, а собака- тюркское.Есть версия, что от татаро-монголов :"ic-бак" - «пес-следопыт», заднеязычный вариант  попал к славянам «съ-бак (а)». Переднеязычный сь-бк стал основой для формы, предшествующей " кебк" (кбк, кбек - кобяк)
В огузо-карлукских наречиях - «кобок» (кобек, кобяк) - пес, собака. Кобяк (собака) - было широко распространенное между тюркскими племенами имя; у ак-ногайцев есть род «кобек»;
кипчакский хан, побежденный Святославом Киевским в 1184 году - «Кобяк».

http://chernyshclub.ucoz.ru/publ/4-1-0-18

Comment: Источник, указанный вами в ссылке - безымянный, неясный, неавторизованный. Рассуждения интересные, но хотелось бы знать, кто их автор.

Comment: Это рассуждения не самого автора (автор сайта - просто любитель собак), он приводит всем известное мнение из Викисловаря   http://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%F1%EE%E1%E0%EA%E0  Общепризнанной этимологии русских слов "собака" и "пёс  нет.Одни этимологи утверждают, что собака - древнее заимствование из иранских языков, вероятно, из языков скифов, другие относят это слово к восточнославянской лексике - от основы соб- при помощи суффикса -ак.  Н. М. Шанский поддерживает первую версию. Фасмер -за ср.-ир. *sabѓka-,Трубачёв - за тюркское происх-е от кобяк. Мне это мнение нравится больше, объясняется иго

Comment: Тем более, что поначалу слово употреблялось как ругательное - явно по отношению к татаро-монголам. У них собака считалась прародителем, именем собаки - кобяками- назывались и их князья, и реки, и селения. А то, что Фасмер говорит, что это не доказано, так и его ср.-иранское происх. тоже не доказано.  У автора вопрос, когда появилось слово - скорее всего, именно во времена татаро-монгольского ига, в ранних памятниках его не было, было "пёс".

Comment: Людмила, так в XII веке или во время ига? Кобяк из ответа, судя по контексту, половецкий хан. Первая же встреча русских с монголами произошла только в 1223 году, а общение и того позже.

Не припомню ни одного монгольского хана Кобяка, да и верховным божеством у них вроде был Тенгри (голубое небо). Хотя православных несториан среди монголов тоже было немало.

Comment: В XII веке, конечно. Это у меня что-то в голове перемкнуло (видимо, после инфаркта), что-то половцев с татаро-монголами соединила. Кобяк - половецкий хан, производивший набеги на Русскую землю в 1170 - 1180 годах. Его и называли собакой, татаро-монголы ни при чём

Comment: >Это у меня что-то в голове перемкнуло (видимо, после инфаркта)  
  
Здоровья Вам. Вы уж поберегите себя.  

Простите, что пофлудил...

Answer (score 4):

Существует версия, согласно которой слово СОБАКА является ранним общевосточнославянским заимствованием из иранских языков Северного Причерноморья (*sabāka - ср.фарси sabah, авест. spaka- - прилаг."собачий", spa - "собака". Иранское слово родственно др.-инд.* Çvā - "собака". Тюркское происхождение, по мнению Фасмера, недоказуемо. (Словари Фасмера М., Черных П.Я.)

Answer (score -1):

Собака имеет объяснение в румынском языке. Слово сформировано из двух частей. СО =  asociat =асоциат, и БАЧ= baci=чабан. Смысл слова "собака" - тот кто помогает чабану пасти овец. Все очень просто.

Comment: Румынский для Вас родной? Я посмотрел по словарям, как переводятся слова "собака", "чабан", "пастух" — не нашёл ничего даже отдалённо похожего. Лже-этимология на этом ресурсе запрещена, поэтому дайте, пожалуйста, ссылки, подтверждающие Ваше мнение.

Answer (score -1):

Даа, наши древние русские приручили собаку, начали думать как ее назвать, ну никак нужного слова не нашли - поехали к тюркам, поклонились и спрашивают - как нам назвать сие животное. А тюрки - "Ну вы тупые, это же собака"

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).